# iOS App not saving TableView results until app is restarted?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I am choosing a particular color theme in my app, it will update the colour chosen (from `myCustomTableView` ) on that page only, when I go to the next page, the color is not the same as what I chose, it has not updated it.

IF I close the app completely (remove from running) and then re-load the app, it will appear with the color I have chosen. It would seem the defaults are not being stored live in the app, only on a restart.

Start of the `.m` file also uses;

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        
        
           NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
            cameraFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"camera_Data.plist"];          
           NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cameraFilePath])
        {
             NSString *bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"camera_Data" ofType:@"plist"];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:cameraFilePath error:nil];
            
        }
        
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

The table is being called in `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        myCustomTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 180, 236, 672) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    else {
        myCustomTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(113, 100, 196, 372) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
    [myCustomTableView setDelegate:self];
    [myCustomTableView setDataSource:self];
     [myCustomTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    [myCustomTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; //[myCustomTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    myCustomTableView.opaque = NO;
    myCustomTableView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    myCustomTableView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    [myCustomTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:myCustomTableView];
    
    
    NSLog(@"theme viewWillAppear is calling");
    myDelegate = (Imax_Battery_AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    
    colorArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red",@"Green",@"Blue",@"Yellow",nil];
    cellImages_Battery=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"batter-red",@"battery-green",@"battery-blue",@"yellow-smbt",nil];
    flagArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:      @"Beanstalk",    @"DJ Talk",     @"View Finder",@"Mojo Art",   @"Creepy Spider",@"Purple Haze",     @"Tribal Fusion",    @"Radio Zapote",    @"Cocanoca",    @"Green Hornet",@"Cactus",   @"Morning Dew",     @"Quite River",    @"Maple",    @"River Amazon",  @"Planet Vulcan",     @"Planet Vulcan",   @"Silent Stars",    @"Helix Nebula",    @"Twilight",     @"Golf ",   @"Football ",     @"Basketball",@"Bowling",   @"Tennis",  nil];
    flagImageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sm-a1",@"sm-a2",@"sm-a3",@"sm-a4",@"sm-a5",@"sm-g1",@"sm-g2",@"sm-g3",@"sm-g4",@"sm-g5",@"sm-n1",@"sm-n2",@"sm-n3",@"sm-n4",@"sm-n5",@"sm-s1",@"sm-s2",@"sm-s3",@"sm-s4",@"sm-s5",@"sm-sp1",@"sm-sp2",@"sm-sp3",@"sm-sp4",@"sm-sp5",nil];
    
    bigFlagImageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a1",@"a2",@"a3",@"a4",@"a5",@"g1",@"g2",@"g3",@"g4",@"g5",@"n1",@"n2",@"n3",@"n4",@"n5",@"s1",@"s2",@"s3",@"s4",@"s5",@"sp1",@"sp2",@"sp3",@"sp4",@"sp5",nil];
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    cameraFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"camera_Data.plist"];
    customArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:cameraFilePath];
    myCustomTableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone    ;
    
    myCustomTableView.rowHeight=48;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    [myCustomTableView reloadData];
   
 
}
```

Row selection is here;

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (IsSelected) {
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tickCurrentPath];
        [[cell viewWithTag:tickImageViewTag] setHidden:YES];
    }
    IsSelected=TRUE;
    NSLog(@"the section is %d snd row %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);
    //Below if Block is written so that the last row with plus and minus bton doesnot show tick image and else it will show
    if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row == [customArray count]) {
        
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[cell viewWithTag:tickImageViewTag] setHidden:YES];
    }
    else {
        self.tickCurrentPath=indexPath;
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[cell viewWithTag:tickImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
    }
    
    
    
    
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *myimageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] ;
    NSLog(@"the image view is as follows %@",myimageView.image);
    
    if (myimageView.image && ![myimageView isHidden]) {
        [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:NO];
        UIImage *myScaledImage=[self scaleImage:myimageView.image toSize:CGSizeMake(87, 296)];
        self.myBatteryImageView.image=myScaledImage;
        NSData *myImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(myScaledImage);

        myDelegate.myselectedImageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myImageData];
        
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
        
        
        [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];
    }
    
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    NSLog(@"battery images are calling RGBetc %d");
    [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:NO];
    NSArray *bigBatteryColorImage=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"battery-red_Big",@"green-battery_Big",@"blue-battery_Big",@"yellow-battery_Big",nil];
    self.myBatteryImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[bigBatteryColorImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"png"]];
    UIImage *savedImage=    self.myBatteryImageView.image;
    NSData *myImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedImage);
    
    myDelegate.myselectedImageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myImageData];
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
    
    
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];}
    
else if(indexPath.section == 2){
    [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:NO];
    self.myBatteryImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[bigFlagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"png"]];       

    UIImage *savedImage=    self.myBatteryImageView.image;
    NSData *myImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedImage);
    
    myDelegate.myselectedImageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myImageData];
    
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
    
    
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];
    
}else if(indexPath.section == 3){
    [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:NO];
    self.myBatteryImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[bigFlagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5] ofType:@"png"]];     
    
    UIImage *savedImage=    self.myBatteryImageView.image;
    NSData *myImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedImage);
    
    myDelegate.myselectedImageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myImageData];
    
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
    
    
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];
    
}else if(indexPath.section == 4){
    [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:NO];
    self.myBatteryImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[bigFlagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+10] ofType:@"png"]];        
    
    UIImage *savedImage=    self.myBatteryImageView.image;
    NSData *myImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedImage);
    
    myDelegate.myselectedImageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myImageData];
    
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
    
    
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];
    
}else if(indexPath.section == 5){
    [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:NO];
    self.myBatteryImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[bigFlagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+15] ofType:@"png"]];        
    
    UIImage *savedImage=    self.myBatteryImageView.image;
    NSData *myImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedImage);
    
    myDelegate.myselectedImageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myImageData];
    
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
    
    
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];
    
}else if(indexPath.section == 6){
    [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:NO];
    self.myBatteryImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[bigFlagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+20] ofType:@"png"]];        
    
    UIImage *savedImage=    self.myBatteryImageView.image;
    NSData *myImageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedImage);
    
    myDelegate.myselectedImageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:myImageData];
    
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
    
    
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];
    
}
    
    else {
        
if ([myDelegate.myselectedImageData count]>0) {
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData removeAllObjects];
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *lastImageFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LastImage.plist"];           
    
    
    [myDelegate.myselectedImageData writeToFile:lastImageFilePath atomically:YES];
    
    
}
        
        
        
        
        [self.myBatteryImageView setHidden:YES];
    }

    
}
```

Comment: I didn’t see any place where you where using UserDefault

Comment: Additional code added - I hope you did not downvote just for that? Hard to get ahead :/

Comment: It would help if you highlighted where you are choosing the colour to be set, and how you are trying to get at this colour. There's a lot of code you've provided that isn't relevant and it makes it hard to understand your problem.

Comment: So there are colors, images, flags etc ,however for this we can just think about the color section of the table, above, check Row Selection, and look for  the code starting `else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    NSLog(@"battery images are calling RGBetc %d");` that method is the area where the color is being chosen, and it changes the visible color on screen.

Comment: I think I understand best your code : in didSelect you setup data in my delegate with image return from bundle (you should really make a method for the delegate setup to make it easier to understand ). Then you try to setup with setting hidden in cell views. This does not work like like : you must reload data to update cell contents/apparence.

Comment: @PtitXav Indeed I do understand now, I am struggling to find a way to update the cell contents so that they are saved without reloading the app again.

Comment: You reload tableView date only in viewDidLoad which is unusefull as tableView reload itself when appearing first time. If you change some background information in didSelect, you should call [myCustomTableView reloadDara] before leaving method.